# Prove this. Automorphism.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ Be automorphisms of $G$. Prove that $\alpha \circ \beta$ is an automorphism of $G$.

Thank you! Please help me in proving this one. I already have an idea but I want to ask for assistance. :)

Comment: Please include that idea then. There is not much of a trick here, just apply the definitions.

Comment: Both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are bijections so $\alpha (\beta)$ must be too. Then check if $\alpha( \beta (x + y ) )= \alpha (\beta (x)) + \alpha( \beta (y))$. It's quite trivial.

Comment: Could you guys show me the complete proof for this? I badly need it for my abstract algebra class. Thanks for the help! 

Answer (score 0):

1. The composition of two homomorphisms is a homomorphism.
2. If $\alpha : G \to H$ and $\beta : H \to K$ are *isomorphisms*, then $\beta \circ \alpha$ is an isomorphism, since you can directly check that $\alpha^{-1} \circ \beta^{-1} : K \to G$ is inverse to $\beta \circ \alpha$.

Comment: One also needs to check that the inverse of a bijective homomorphism is itself a homomorphism.